# JavaEE 6: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override

Tags: ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I have a business interface being implemented by two EJBs.

**UserManagementService**

```
@Remote
public interface UserManagementService {
    // ...
}
```

**UserManagementServiceJpaImpl**

```
@Stateless(name="userManagementServiceJpaImpl")
public class UserManagementServiceJpaImpl implements UserManagementService {

    @EJB(beanName="userManagementDaoJpaImpl")
    private UserManagementDao userManagementDao;

    // ...
}
```

**UserManagementServiceMockImpl**

```
@Stateless(name="userManagementServiceMockImpl")
public class UserManagementServiceMockImpl implements UserManagementService {   

    @EJB(beanName="userManagementDaoMockImpl")
    private UserManagementDao userManagementDao;

    // ...

}
```

When I deploy the application to Glassfish 3.1 I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name com.transbinary.imdb.service.UserManagementService for EJB : userManagementServiceMockImpl
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1550)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:202)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:577)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:213)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:672)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:689)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:404)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:404)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1535)
    ... 23 more
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try looking into server startup logs where JNDI binding of the interfaces are shown, check whether its already deployed on the server. Most probably this error arises having same interface names in different packages or including same interface in multiple jars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default GlassFish Server specific default JNDI names are applied automatically for backward compatibility. So `com.transbinary.imdb.service.UserManagementService` is the the default JNDI name for both the implementations of `UserManagementService` interface. Which was why I was gettting `javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException` exception.

But because the EJB 3.1 specification defines portable EJB JNDI names, there is less need for GlassFish Server specific JNDI names.

To disable GlassFish Server specific JNDI names for an EJB module, set the value of `disable-nonportable-jndi-names` element to `true`. The default is `false`.

It solved the problem.

Resource: http://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Developer+Handoff+to+QA+for+EJB-8+%28Option+to+disable+GlassFish-specific+JNDI%29

Answer (score 8):

GlassFish restart. (It worked for me.)

Comment: Fixed my issue too.. funny how true this is.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8

Answer (score 2):

I got this same exception.
In my case I changed my code from 
`@Stateless(mappedName = "whatever")` 
to instead be 
`@Stateless(name = "whatever")` 
and it solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Make use of rebind instead of bind and it should work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using JBoss5.1GA and i had two EJBs implementing a common local Business Interface...

I Follow the idea suggested by @Christo Smal, and it work for me.... Another Observation: I was deploying an ear which contains the two EJBs at two differents EJB jars; e.g:

```
   Ear File:
   * Jar File1: Containing EJB1
   * Jar File2: Containing EJB2
   * lib/dummy.jar: Library containing the Business Local interface
```