# EJB Container initialization error : Error while binding JNDI name

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to deploy an Enterprise Web Application that i have created using Java Language. When i deploy the project i'm getting this error from Glassfish Server Log. I'm using a Stateless Remote Session Bean named "MiuUsertableFacade" that interacts with the Class Library.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Info:   file:/C:/Users/miura/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RioGamesOnlinePortalApplication/dist/gfdeploy/RioGamesOnlinePortalApplication/RioGamesOnlinePortal_jar/_RioGamesOnlinePortalPU logout successful
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name miuusertablefacade#com.riogames.Entity.MiuUsertableFacadeRemote for EJB MiuUsertableFacade

.......

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaEE 6: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443306/javaee-6-javax-naming-namealreadyboundexception-use-rebind-to-override)

Comment: Show ur full code,then only we can figure out your problem and help you.