# EJB Container initialization error : Error while binding JNDI name?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

Spent all day trying to get this to work with no success. Any ideas how this error can be solved?

Here are the three projects that are associated and their structures:
[image]

**BasicSessionEJB.java**

```
package ejbModule.test;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class BasicSessionEJB
 */
@Stateless( mappedName="ejb/BasicSessionEJB" )
public class BasicSessionEJB implements BasicSessionEJBRemote {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public BasicSessionEJB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello, EJB Wolrd!";
   }

}
```

**BasicServlet.java**

```
package src;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ejb.*;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class BasicServlet
 */


public class BasicServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB private ejbModule.test.BasicSessionEJBRemote basicSessionEJB;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public BasicServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Servlet Message:" + basicSessionEJB.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception e){
             throw new ServletException (e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("Message:" + basicSessionEJB.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e){
             throw new ServletException (e);
        }
    }



}
```

**BasicSessionEJBRemote.java**

```
package ejbModule.test;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface BasicSessionEJBRemote {
    String getMessage();
}
```

**EJBDesktopClient.java**

```
package appClientModule.test;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class EJBDesktopClient {

    public EJBDesktopClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       try {
           Context ctx = new InitialContext();
           ejbModule.test.BasicSessionEJBRemote bean = (ejbModule.test.BasicSessionEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb/BasicSessionEJB");
           System.out.println("Message: " + bean.getMessage());
       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

}
```

**The error log**

```
2016-04-24T01:36:18.285+0100|Severe: Exception while loading the app
2016-04-24T01:36:18.287+0100|Severe: The web application [unknown] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1] (value [org.glassfish.pfl.dynamic.codegen.impl.CurrentClassLoader$1@77b3a7d8]) and a value of type [org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] (value [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
2016-04-24T01:36:18.297+0100|Severe: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name ejb/BasicSessionEJB for EJB BasicSessionEJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1620)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:190)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:322)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:266)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:85)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:657)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:429)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:429)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:4952)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1607)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the approaches mentioned in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443306/javaee-6-javax-naming-namealreadyboundexception-use-rebind-to-override.

Comment: @aribeiro yes i did with no success.

Comment: All the approaches resulted always in the same error?

Comment: did you try restarted the glassfish server ?

Comment: Hi, have you fixed this error?