# EJB stateless session bean deployment exception in glassfish 4.0 application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1, stateless-session-bean

```
[2016-04-29T12:42:43.821+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE][][javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=44> _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1461913963821] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name adder for EJB AdderBean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1620)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:190)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:322)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:257)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:85)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:657)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:4952)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1607)     
  ... 71 more
```

My *ejb-jar.xml* is:

```
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
       <session>
            <ejb-name>myadder</ejb-name> 
             <bussiness-remote>mypack.Adder</bussiness-remote>
             <ejb-class>mypack.AdderBean</ejb-class>
             <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
             <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
       </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

*glassfish-ejb-jar.xml* is:

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
    <glassfish-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>myadder</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>adder</jndi-name>
    </glassfish-enterprise-bean>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

I am using GlassFish server and want to deploy it so that I can use it for stand alone application.

And my remote interface is named `Adder` and its implementation `AdderBean`.

[image]

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443306/javaee-6-javax-naming-namealreadyboundexception-use-rebind-to-override

Comment: Thanks aribeiro !
but now i m getting the jndi naming lookup problem as shown below

Comment: import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import mypack.*;

public class StatelessSessionClient
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {  try{

     System.out.println("welcome to ejb session stateless client");
      
     InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext();
     Adder ob=(Adder)ctx.lookup("java:global/adder");     
     int res=ob.add(5,4);
     System.out.println("result is :  "+res);
        
        }
       catch(Exception e)
  {
         e.printStackTrace();
 }
  }

}

Comment: javax.naming.NamingException:Lookupfailedfor 'java:global/adder' in SerialContext[myEnv=java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url
.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is avax.naming.NameNotFoundException:addernotfound]at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)atcom.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: adder not found

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException
```

There is another (or the same bean) is already deployed and bound with the name "adder". So, you need to clean the deployment folder or rename your bean